# MongoDb c# Driver typed Builder with string args

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-csharp-2.0

How can I implement a typed `Builder` using `string` `fieldname` and `value`, like in the following code:

```
Builders<Profile>.Filter.Eq(fieldName, value)
```

I can implement it with `BsonDocument` data type, but I need to retrieve a typed `Profile` `FilterDifinition`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an implicit conversion from `string` to `FilterDefinition` so you can use it just like you did. For example:

```
var profile = await collection.Find(Builders<Profile>.Filter.Eq("Name", "bar")).SingleAsync();
```